# undimensioned array field, its use?

Tags: c

```
struct test{
    unsigned long int asd[][3][6];
};
```

`sizeof(struct test)` returns 0. So, if that is an exact alias of

```
struct test{
    unsigned long int asd[0][3][6];
};
```

is there any practical use for such a field declaration? You may consider also the template metaprogramming stuff, which is always surprising.

Comment: "template metaprogramming" would be C++; you've tagged your question as C...

Comment: I wasn't aware the first code snippet was valid C.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: An undimensioned array is an incomplete type, and thus it can only be used in certain contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example demonstrates the use of a *flexible array member*, a feature of C99. However in order to get that snippet to compile, you need to have another member in your `struct`, ie:

```
struct test{
    int a;
    unsigned long int asd[][3][6];
};
```

[This documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Zero-Length.html) on gcc tells you why `sizeof` evaulates to zero, and the syntactical difference of a normal array:

> In ISO C90, you would have to give contents a length of 1, which means
>   either you waste space or complicate the argument to malloc.
>
> In ISO C99, you would use a flexible array member, which is slightly
>   different in syntax and semantics:
>
> - Flexible array members are written as contents[] without the 0.
> - Flexible array members have incomplete type, and so the sizeof operator may not be applied. As a quirk of the original implementation
>     of zero-length arrays, sizeof evaluates to zero.
> - Flexible array members may only appear as the last member of a struct that is otherwise non-empty.
> - A structure containing a flexible array member, or a union containing such a structure (possibly recursively), may not be a
>     member of a structure or an element of an array. (However, these uses
>     are permitted by GCC as extensions.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a "flexible array member", described in section 6.7.2.1 paragraph 16 of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (3.7MB PDF).

This is a new feature in C99; some compilers (particularly Microsoft's) might not support it.

Note that a flexible array member must be the last member of a struct, and it cannot be the *only* member.

It's a replacement for the "struct hack", described in question 2.6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use undimensioned arrays in systems with custom memory allocators where you have limited ammount of memory. Say, in embedded software.

If you have a struct defined as:

```
struct test
{
    int a;
    unsigned long int asd[][6][3];
};
```

and a memory pool:

```
int *b = new unsigned long int[1000];
```

you can 'allocate' memory and use the structure as follows:

```
test *t;
t = (test*)b;
t->asd[1][2][3] = 1;
```

This approach is more flexible than making an array of specified dimensions. Of course you can always use a structure like

```
struct test2
{
    int a;
    unsigned long int ***asd;
};
```

but you'll need to initialize the pointer separately and the pointer itself needs 4 bytes.
As a bonus of not using a pointer the structure is represented as a linear memory chunk and can be serialized as is.